при запросе пользователя длиной более чем в 1 строку почему то пропадает иконка

<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:id="@+id/right_chat_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="80sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorSecondaryVariant"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/right_chat_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
            android:padding="5sp"
            android:textColor="?attr/colorOnSecondary" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/person"
            android:layout_width="25sp"
            android:layout_height="25sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/right_chat_text_view"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person" />


android:maxWidth="270sp" - всё, что нужно было сделать, это добавить этот параметр в TextView.

Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].
